# Десериализация c#

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

Пишу консольное приложение которое будет делать запрос к api и полученный ответ выводить на консоль. Но не могу отформатировать вывод, api выдает много ненужной инфы, не могу понять как это правильно десериализовать

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("input country name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

var client = new RestClient("https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/name/" + name);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "7ad6273cfamshbec0ad25232fe87p1ade6ejsnd0fa171f378e");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string stream = response.Content;

CountryInfo countryInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountryInfo>(stream);
Console.WriteLine(countryInfo.Name, countryInfo.CountryCode, countryInfo.Capital, countryInfo.Area, countryInfo.Population, countryInfo.Region);
```

"CountryInfo" - класс, в котором я описал все необходимые мне сущности с геттерами сеттерами, но привести ответ к этому виду никак не получается.

```csharp
public class CountryInfo
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "numericCode")]
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "capital")]
    public string Capital { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "area")]
    public float Area { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "popilation")]
    public decimal Population { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

То, что записалось в переменную, отвечающую за ответ api

```json
[
  {
    "name": "United States",
    "topLevelDomain": [
      ".us"
    ],
    "alpha2Code": "US",
    "alpha3Code": "USA",
    "callingCodes": [
      "1"
    ],
    "capital": "Washington, D.C.",
    "altSpellings": [
      "US",
      "USA",
      "United States of America"
    ],
    "region": "Americas",
    "subregion": "Northern America",
    "population": 321645000,
    "latlng": [
      38,
      -97
    ],
    "demonym": "American",
    "area": 9629091,
    "gini": 48,
    "timezones": [
      "UTC-12:00",
      "UTC-11:00",
      "UTC-10:00",
      "UTC-09:00",
      "UTC-08:00",
      "UTC-07:00",
      "UTC-06:00",
      "UTC-05:00",
      "UTC-04:00",
      "UTC+10:00",
      "UTC+12:00"
    ],
    "borders": [
      "CAN",
      "MEX"
    ],
    "nativeName": "United States",
    "numericCode": "840",
    "currencies": [
      "USD",
      "USN",
      "USS"
    ],
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ],
    "translations": {
      "de": "Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika",
      "es": "Estados Unidos",
      "fr": "États-Unis",
      "ja": "アメリカ合衆国",
      "it": "Stati Uniti D'America"
    },
    "relevance": "3.5"
  }
]
```

Comment: Говорите про JSON, а кидаете код запроса. Где сам JSON то?

Comment: Может я совсем дурак и ничего не понимааю, но сам json файл приложение не загружает, в визуализаторе текста значение в переменной, куда записывается ответ вот такое 
[{"name":"United States","topLevelDomain":[".us"],"alpha2Code":"US","alpha3Code":"USA","callingCodes":["1"],"capital":"Washington, D.C.","altSpellings":["US","USA","United States of America"],"region":"Americas","subregion":"Northern America","population":321645000,"latlng":[38.0,-97.0],"demonym":"American","area":9629091.0,"gini":48.0,}

Comment: В вопрос его, целиком (валидный), а также все классы начиная от `CountryInfo` (в который вы десериализуете).

Comment: Поправил, но других классов, относящихся к этому там больше нет.

Comment: То, что у вас JSON в `[..]`, а десериализация идет в чистый `CountryInfo` не смущает? Это же массив...